# Destructing assignment to swap the values in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-assignment, destructuring

I am revising JavaScript and came to following ES6 example.

```
let a = 8, b = 6;
// change code below this line
[a,b] = [b,a];
// change code above this line
console.log(a); // a is 6
console.log(b); // b is 8
```

Not able to figure out how this is working, as we have assignment operator with both side arrays.

Comment: From the title and the tags, you seem to already know that it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). What further information do you need?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Learning destructuring assignment and not able to figure out how this working as it seems different than = operator behavior right-to-left

Comment: No, there's no change in behavior for the assignment operator. Values are still assigned from right to left.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, but the assignment is done on arrays?

Comment: Array elements or object properties.

Comment: May be I need to explore more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring basically separates an array or an object into separate variables. That is what happens on the left side. Exemple:

```js
var foo = [1, 2]
var [a, b] = foo; // creates new variables a and b with values from the array foo

console.log(a); // prints "1"
console.log(b); // prints "2"
```

On the right side, you are creating an array with the values `[b, a]` which will be destructured. As a result, the two variables are switched.

Comment: Thanks, I get confused with statement [a,b] = [b,a].